# Scanner doesn't update input when returning to method Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a word-guessing game code. The main calls the **inputTake** method, which asks for input of a word consisting 5 English letters only, and returns is. Before returning the word, it calls another method, **checkInput**, to make sure the input is valid. If the input isn't valid, the **checkInput** method prints an error message and calls **inputTake** to let the user try again.

But when the first input is invalid, **checkInput** calls **inputTake** and then the second input is valid everything seems to work alright. The problem is that the method returns the first, invalid input, and not the valid input.

I tried initializing Scanner in the main and giving it to the method as parameter, but that doesn't help.

Below is the code I wrote, any thoughts? Any help is welcome

---

Main:

```
Board board1 = new Board();
        
String guess = board1.inputTake();
```

Board:

```
// take input - print a message and calls the checkInput method with the String inputed.
public String inputTake(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess;

    System.out.println("choose a word, pick carefully: ");
    guess = scan.next();
    
    // we gotta check whether the input's valid before we return it!
    checkInput(guess);
        
    return guess;
    }
    
    /* checks whether a given String is made out of 5 english language letters. 
     * if it is, program continues normally.
     * if not, it prints error message and calls the InputTake method again.
     */
public void checkInput(String input) {
    boolean isGood = true;
        
    // check if 5 letters
    if(input.length() != 5)
        isGood = false;
        
    // check if all are english
    if(!input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) 
          isGood = false;
        
    if(isGood == false) {
        System.out.println("make sure your guess consists of 5 english letters, try again.");
        inputTake();
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are reading from stdin, do not `scan.close();` - you are closing stdin.

Comment: thanks for your help! you're right. unfortunately this doesn't fix the bug.

Comment: No matter what `checkInput()` finds - the `inputTake()` method returns whatever was entered first (i.e. the output of the recursive `inputTake()` call is ignored).

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I can't find a way to solve it. Got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that your `inputTake()` call inside `checkInput()` doesn't do what you want. You can try this:

```
// take input - print a message and calls the checkInput method with the String inputed.
public String inputTake(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess;

    System.out.println("choose a word, pick carefully: ");
    guess = scan.next();
        
    // we gotta check whether the input's valid before we return it!
    if(!isGoodInput(guess)) {
        System.out.println("make sure your guess consists of 5 english letters, try again.");
        guess = inputTake();
    }
    return guess;
}
        
/* checks whether a given String is made out of 5 english language letters. 
* if it is, program continues normally.
*/
public boolean isGoodInput(String input) {
    return input.length() == 5 && input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget: you need to check the input again if it wasn't a good input first time: it might not be a good input the second (or third etc) time as well.

Comment: @AndyTurner That is handled by the method's recursive nature.

Comment: this work perfectly and also looks much better and efficient. thank you so much!